# Not getting the values of ControlGroup which has controlArray

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which sets input to the child component...In the child component i am creating ControlArray based on the input got from the parent and adding the ControlArray to the main ControlGroup like this http://plnkr.co/edit/qyHAfkxHGa7KtGkL4Yf9?p=preview ...But when i make changes in the form and submit i am not getting the values correctly...Somebody please tell me where i am doing wrong.
Here OperationsData is the input,based on it i am creating controlgroup and i am pushing into controlarray like this

```
   for(var i=0;i<this.OperationsData.length;i++){
  this.operations.push(
  new ControlGroup({
    name: new Control(this.OperationsData[i].name, Validators.required),
    place: new Control(this.OperationsData[i].place, Validators.required)
  })
);
}
```

What is wrong in my demo...How can i get the correct values when i submit the form...

Comment: I'm seeing correct values in `console` being logged, what's the issue ?

Comment: Just now i updated the plunker brother...I didn't reinitialise the controlarray,now i did

Comment: So this fixed your problem?

Comment: Actually i am not yet finished...checkout this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/qyHAfkxHGa7KtGkL4Yf9?p=preview ... Here when i submit the form the ControlArray is present in a object...That makes my output look like this
{
Operations:{
OperationsArray:[....]
}
}
Is it possible to make my output like this
{
OperationsArray:[...]
} 
I mean the ControlArray Should be directly place in the main ControlGroup

Comment: I dont know whether it is the best approach to follow or not...Is there any good approach to have a controlArray which consists of controlGroups?